# Need recommendation on updating secrets to KeyVault

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I am deploying an Azure function app that calls backend api which is secured by API Keys.  The app will be deployed using Azure DevOps pipeline; the API key will be stored as secret in KeyVault, i am using Bicep files for infra definition and Yaml pipeline for deploying Infra and Application.  Below are questions i have w.r.t. KeyVault updates,

1. Should pipeline be responsible for updating secrets in KeyVault?  If so, is it recommended to maintain Secrets in DevOps variable group (pad locked), or, is there a better/more secure approach?
2. Should the secrets in KeyVault be updated/maintained manually? Going with this approach our pipelines will be less mature as there would still be manual intervention/not-immutable - consider there is recreation of an environment.

I would like to know the best practices on the above, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the answer is *it depends*. Which makes this question one that might get some opinion-based answers. If you look at the Microsoft documentation, it states:

> Don't set secret variables in your YAML file. Operating systems often log commands for the processes that they run, and you wouldn't want the log to include a secret that you passed in as an input. Use the script's environment or map the variable within the `variables` block to pass secrets to your pipeline.
>
> You need to set secret variables in the pipeline settings UI for your pipeline. These variables are scoped to the pipeline in which you set them. You can also set [secret variables in variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#reference-secret-variables-in-variable-groups).

Source: [Define variables - Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

Despite this, you should ask yourself the question where the *ownership* of those secrets lies. And the owner should be the one in charge.

- Maintaining these secrets in KeyVault means you don't even need secrets in your pipeline. This means a clear separation of responsibilities.
- Maintaining these secrets in your pipeline enables you to update them together with the code that uses them. This ties the secret to the consuming code.

Both are good scenario's depending on where the responsibility lies.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for late acknowledgment  I agree with your thoughts, broadly "Secrets (should)/(preferred to) be centralized if there is different team (Ops) managing the lifetime of this secrets, or/and, if the secrets are used by multiple client apps.  Secrets (should)/(preferred to) be delivered through pipeline variables (padlocked), if they are maintained/managed by individual development teams.  Additionally, in the former, the repeatability of deployment can be achieved by providing Managed Identity based access to client-apps for centralized KeyVaults."